# What is that number on top of my friend's profile picture?

Tags: draw-something

When I play Draw Something with a friend, my friend's profile has a number shown on top of it. Sometimes, it says 1, or 2... what does this number represent? It doesn't have nothing to do with the number of guesses as sometimes I start playing with someone and they have a high number on top.

Comment: can you provide a picture please?

Answer (score 5):

The number on top of your friends portrait represents the amount of times you've guessed eachothers drawings correctly in a row. Skipping a drawing will forfeit the counter and reset it.